# How to calculate average unique rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

I created table which contains Country and CustomerId Columns that all row describes order:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CountryRegionCode
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader, Sales.SalesTerritory
WHERE Sales.SalesOrderHeader.TerritoryID = Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID:
```

[image]

I need to calculate the average of orders per customer in all countries together and for US Country in same output table.

the average is: (number of customers in the world) / (number of orders in the world)

(number of customers in US) / (number of orders in US)

output:

```
 CountryRegionCode   | Average orders per customer
      World          |        ?
       US            |        ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the world includes the US, then you pretty much want two queries:

```
SELECT 'World', COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)
FROM s.SalesOrderHeader soh JOIN
     s.SalesTerritory st
     ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'US', COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)
FROM s.SalesOrderHeader soh JOIN
     s.SalesTerritory st
     ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
WHERE st.CountryRegionCode = 'US';
```

Note:

- This introduces proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- This has table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division, so this produces a number with decimal places.